# Holonomy group and irreducible $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-connections

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory, holonomy

Let $P\to M$ be a $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-principal bundle over a closed connected manifold $M$ and let $A$ be a flat connexion form on $P$. Fixing $x\in M$ we have a homomorphism
$$
\mathrm{Hol}_x(A) : \pi_1(M,x) \to \mathrm{SU}(2)
$$
given by the holonomy of a loop (it is well defined since $A$ is flat). Since $\pi_1(M,x)$ is a countable group, its image via $\mathrm{Hol}_x(A)$ is countable inside $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. So $\mathrm{Hol}_x(A)$ is not surjective for $A$ flat.

Now, our flat connection $A$ is called *irreducible* if the image of $\pi_1(M,x)$ by $\mathrm{Hol}_x(A)$ is equal to $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and not a proper subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, i.e. if $\mathrm{Hol}_x(A)$ is surjective.

**Question :** How can a connection be at the same time *flat* and *irreducible* if $\mathrm{Hol}_x(A)$ is never surjective for $A$ flat ?

Comment: The fundamental group is countable and SU(2) is not, so there is no surjective homomorphism from the first to the second.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks, that partially answer my question. I'll precise it now.

Comment: Apparently they cannot be. But a connection can be irreducible without being flat; the holonomy is a map on the loop space, which reduces to the fundamental group when the connection is flat.

Comment: @ChrisGerig Irreducible non-flat connections isn't the problem. My question is about irreducible flat connections. Apparently they don't exist. But they certainly do exist in the litterature, e.g. there are lots of papers about the moduli space of irreducible flat $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-connections on a closed surface $\Sigma$ or on a homology 3-sphere.

Comment: Well that's because the definitions in the literature vary, I think. With your definition, it cannot exist, you literally proved it. But the other definition I know of is: the centralizer of the holonomy group $H$ in $G$ (which is $SU(2)$ here) is equal to the center of $G$ (which is $\lbrace\pm1\rbrace$ here).

Comment: @ChrisGerig Yes. Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: The standard notion of an irreducible representation $\rho: H\to GL(n,C)$ of a group $H$ to $GL(n,C)$ is that $C^n$ contains no proper $\rho(H)$-invariant subspaces. With this standard definition, there is abundance of irreducible representations of finitely generated groups into $SU(2)$, e.g. representations of fundamental groups of surfaces of genus $\ge 2$, various 3-manifold groups. For instance, if $M$ is an integer homology 3-sphere which is not $S^3$, then there is always an irreducible representation $\pi_1(M)\to SU(2)$.